# How to correctly use this.id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and HTML. I tried creating a button that turns white when clicked, although every time i run this code it get the error of `TypeError: Cannot read prperty 'value' of null`, telling me I am not calling the button properly. When searching around online, I found that I should be able to use this.id, but that also has not worked

```
function newBtn(num){
 var n = 0;
 while(n<num){
  n++;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.className = 'dots';
  btn.setAttribute('value', 1);
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'dot'+n);
  btn.onclick = light(this.id);
  btn.style.left = '200';
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
 }
}

function light(id){
 var dot=document.getElementById(id);
 var value = dot.value;
 if (value<4){
    dot.style.background="white";
 }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not the same as Java. Please clarify what language you are asking about and provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: You're *calling* `light` when you want to *assign* it to the `onclick` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `btn.id` instead of `this.id` as `this` refers to the `window` inside your function. You should not be assigning the result of invoking the `light` function to `btn.onclick`; you should assign the function itself to it, with the `id` parameter given to it using `Function.prototype.bind`.

```js
function newBtn(num){
 var n = 0;
 while(n<num){
  n++;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.className = 'dots';
  btn.setAttribute('value', 1);
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'dot'+n);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = light.bind(null, btn.id);
  btn.style.left = '200';
 }
}

function light(id){
 var dot=document.getElementById(id);
 var value = dot.value;
 if (value<4){
    dot.style.background="white";
 }
}
newBtn(5);
```

It would be much easier to simply pass the button's value or the button itself to the `light` function, as you really do not need to query the DOM to get the button when you already obtained a reference to it when you created it using `document.createElement`. The `onclick` function is always called with the HTML element itself set as the `this` value, so you can use that.

```js
function newBtn(num){
 var n = 0;
 while(n<num){
  n++;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.className = 'dots';
  btn.setAttribute('value', 1);
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'dot'+n);
  btn.onclick = light;
  btn.style.left = '200';
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
 }
}

function light(){
 var value = this.value;
 if (value<4){
    this.style.background="white";
 }
}
newBtn(5);
```

Comment: `btn.onclick = light(btn.id);` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `btn.onclick` should be assigned  a function, but you are assigning it result of invoking that function directly.

Comment: @selbie Sorry, I did not notice that. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: There's no need to use `bind` - setting the `onclick` callback will naturally bind `this` to the element. That was a decent workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

Set the onClick callback with `btn.onclick = light` and `this` will refer to the button inside `light()` like you are expecting. You don't even need to give them IDs in this case, and can reuse this function and bind it to any eventListener on any element.

Also, as a side note, `button.value` does not mean anything (it basically evaluates to `"" < 4` which coerces to `0 < 4` and always returns `true`).

```js
function light() {
 if (this.value < 4)
    this.style.background = "white";
}

function newBtn(num) {

 let n = 0;
 while(n++ < num) {
 
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  
  btn.className = 'dots',
  btn.setAttribute('value', 1),
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'dot'+n),
  btn.style.left = '200',
  btn.onclick = light;
  
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  
 }
}

newBtn(5);
```